# Handling to reopen fragment on back press

Tags: android, fragment

Let me explain my application first.

I have an activity and fragments in it. I'm opening fragmentA onCreate of application. In fragmentA,before i open fragmentB by using support fragment manager's replace() method, i call a webService for some json datas.

Then i open fragmentB with these json datas. After i opened the fragmentB, i want to turn back to fragmentA by using device's default backbutton, and i don't want to handle backButtonPress(). Just go back to previous fragment. My app does this.

Here is the question. When i press back button, my fragmentA calls the service again and it affects the user to wait. But how can i just turn to the previous fragment ?

I am looking for the best solution to turn previous fragment.

Comment: This might be due to the place you put the call to webService. For example, if you put it in onCreate(), maybe it will not be called the secodn time? I think only onStart is called when using replace -> Back. 
Then, another way to do it is to keep a flag in the activity to remember that the webService has been called once already. I am sure there are more ways.

Comment: @Poutrathor that make sense. Should we save some state at onCreate() or somewhere else ?

Comment: "Should we save some state at onCreate() or somewhere else ?" I am sorry, I don't understand what you just asked?

Comment: Have you added your fragment to Backstack?